# css and js path corrupted in loading view page on edit method in laravel 5.58

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5.8

I am new in laravel   so  i doing a project in laravel .I need to  update a  record  so when i load the edit form then js and css path are corrupted if i don't pass   update id among the url   then there is no problem.

Below is my code

edit url is

```
<a href="/editmarriagepackage/1">Edit</a>
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/editmarriagepackage/{id}','AdminController@editmarriagepackage');
```

Admincontroller.php

```
  public function editmarriagepackage($id){

      $data['action']='/updatemarriagepackage';
      return view('admin.Addmarriagepackage',$data);

  }
```

header.php

```
 <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="assets/css/material-dashboard2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="assets/demo/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

The problem is  css and js path is appear as http://127.0.0.1:8000/editmarriagepackage/assets/css/material-dashboard2.min.css and http://127.0.0.1:8000/editmarriagepackage/assets/demo/demo.css

Here "editmarriagepackage"  is unwanted.Actual path must be http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets/css/material-dashboard2.min.css if it is this then no problem.This issue not occurs when i use Route::get('/editmarriagepackage','AdminController@editmarriagepackage');

so  the problem is when i pass id through url then function name in the controller is appeared in css and js path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your views you have to generate static assets files with the `asset` helper.
This generate the correct path based on the document_root.

So, assuming the file(s)/folder(s) are placed in the **public** folder:

**Without Blade**

```html
<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="<?php echo asset('assets/css/material-dashboard2.min.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
<link href="<?php echo asset('assets/demo/demo.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**With Blade** (recommended)

```html
<!-- CSS Files -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/css/material-dashboard2.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
<link href="{{ asset('assets/demo/demo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
```